# Writing the product of cycles as disjoint cycles, but yielding to different result when applying it.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-presentation, permutation-cycles

I'm studying the symmetric group $S_n$ of permutations from $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ to itself.
I'm doing a problem where I have to show that $$S_4\cong \langle a,b~|~a^4=b^2=(ba)^3=1\rangle.$$
I thought the following: in general, a $k$-cycle has order $k$ in $S_n$ for $k\leq n$ (we can think about $\pmod n$ but I want to simplify it).

On the other hand, I've alredy proved that $S_n=\langle (1~2),(1~2\cdots~n)\rangle$, so $\langle(1~2)(1~2~3~4)\rangle S_4$.

Let $a:=(1~2~3~4),~b=(1~2)$.

Indeed, $a^4=(1~2~3~4)^4=1$, $b^2=(1~2)^2=1$, and I was checking that third condition, $(ba)^3=1$.

Doing the product of cycles, I got that $(1~2)(1~2~3~4)=(2~3~4)$.

However, I'm surely making a big mistake when checking with an example. Consider the set $(1,2,3,4)$ (which is a $4$-tuple). Then, applying $a$ to that set it becomes $\color{red}{\text{NOT}}$ $\color{red}{(4,1,2,3)}$, $(2,3,4,1)$ and then $(1,2)$, it will be $(1,3,4,2)$.

<s>*But when I apply the cycle $(2~3~4)$ to the $4$-tuple $(1,2,3,4)$, $1$ is fixed and they're alredy different.* In fact</s> I get $(1,3,4,2)$ <s>which is different to $(4,2,1,3)$</s>.

What am I doing wrong here? I want the product $ba$ so then I compute $(ba)^3$ and check that it is indeed $1$ (and in this case, $(2~3~4)^3=1$).

**Edit:** red text is what I was doing wrong and now changing it with help of the comments.

**Edit 2:** Solved!!

Comment: If you apply $(1,2,3,4)$ to $1$, you get $2$.

Comment: Indeed, the mapping $(1~2~3~4)$ sends: $1\mapsto 2,~2\mapsto 3, 3\mapsto 4, 4\mapsto 1$. So $(1~2~3~4)$ applied to $(1,2,3,4)$ is $(4,1,2,3)$, isn't it?

Comment: You're applying the inverse of the permutation: it's not that $1$ moves to position $2$, rather it's that the $1$, regardless of position, becomes a $2$ in its position. (The effect of this is that the $2$ moves to position $1$ which is why these are inverse actions!)

Comment: Right, I've been confusing positions and numbers the whole time since I'm learning this topic. When we apply a permutation, we are changing the numbers, not positions then, right?

Comment: Thank you both, I figured it out :)